# Is "!=" not the opposite of "="?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why if I put = it brings me the correct result and when I put != it brings me the full list instead of the different ones.

```
SELECT     * 
FROM      library, crime_data 
WHERE     crime_data.id=$oreo 
AND       crime_data.isbn != library.isbn 
AND       crime_data.visibility='0' 
GROUP BY  library.isbn
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: SELECT * FROM library, crime_data is a cross join. Apply this and see yourself the difference between = and !=

Comment: Try and describe in plain text what you are trying to do when you use `!=` in a join in this way.

Comment: It would be even better if you could create the tables in the http://sqlfiddle.com/ and say what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `!=` and `=` relate is easy to see with [a simple example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/21578):

```
SELECT
    1=1,
    1=2,
    1=NULL,
    NULL=NULL,

    1<>1,
    1<>2,
    1<>NULL,
    NULL<>NULL
```

*(I'm using the standard `<>` operator rather than the MySQL specific one `!=`, but [they're equivalent](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal)).*

```
+-----+-----+--------+-----------+------+------+---------+------------+
| 1=1 | 1=2 | 1=NULL | NULL=NULL | 1<>1 | 1<>2 | 1<>NULL | NULL<>NULL |
+-----+-----+--------+-----------+------+------+---------+------------+
|   1 |   0 |   NULL |      NULL |    0 |    1 |    NULL |       NULL |
+-----+-----+--------+-----------+------+------+---------+------------+
```

So the union of rows where `crime_data.isbn = library.isbn` and `crime_data.isbn != library.isbn` does not contain the row total; it excludes all rows where there's at least one `NULL` operator.

Answer (score 8):

You have to think conceptually of what SQL is doing from a set theory viewpoint. When you join two table, the concept is  a Cartesian Join – each row of table A is joined with each row of table B. So if you have table of 10 rows and a table of 20 rows and join them, you get a join of 200 rows.

Now when you select using the “=” only rows where the values are equal, usually few, are selected. When you use “!=” it select all the OTHER rows.

---

**Edit to answer comment "how should it be".**

```
Select *
From library
Where Not Exists 
    (
        Select 1 
        From  crime_data 
        Where crime_data.isbn = library.isbn 
    )
```

Comment: So, how should it be?

Comment: +1 I would suggest introduce the use of `Join` to the Op

Comment: So I _think_ you're looking for rows in table A that do not have a matching row in table B. For that see edit in answer. Would be good also to read in detail on the web what SLQ join means. Helps when you can kind of picture the underlying concept which is a bit strange.